# USB sticks not detected in file system nor by GParted (Linux Mint)

Tags: linux-mint, mount, usb, file-format

I am trying to make an installable Windows USB stick in Linux Mint. It is not detecting the two drives I am attempting to format.

From my understanding, I need to format the drive with GParted before I can see it in the file explorer. But GParted doesn't see them. `fdisk` also does not see them.

I cannot find any information about what to do if `lsusb` detects a USB stick but `fdisk` does not.

How can I fix this?

`lsusb` lists them and `dmesg` shows the following:

```
[  914.805322] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 14
[  916.383535] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[  916.584712] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=3070
[  916.584716] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  916.584719] usb 1-4: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[  916.584720] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Ralink
[  916.584722] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 1.0
[  916.751777] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[  916.946819] ieee80211 phy11: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 3070, rev 0201 detected
[  917.001365] ieee80211 phy11: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 0005 detected
[  917.002026] ieee80211 phy11: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
```

So it seems to me that the USB stick should be mounting no problem?

Comment: Your `dmesg` output shows a WLAN USB stick or device, not a flash memory USB stick. Remove the memory USB stick, type `dmesg`, remember the last timestamp (first number), put in the memory USB stick again, edit question with all new lines that appear in `dmesg` after the remembered timestamp. If it's still a WLAN USB stick, then that's what it is, and you won't be able to put files on it, neither in Windows, nor in Linux.